# Error when comparing two DateTime objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm comparing two DateTime objects (at least I think I am, they look slightly different in the console output below).

```
p DateTime.now
p current_user.created_at #schema.rb states that this is a datetime field
difference = DateTime.now - current_user.created_at
p difference
```

Console output

```
Mon, 04 Oct 2010 22:56:32 +1000
Sat, 14 Aug 2010 20:51:08 EST +10:00
```

Error (on the `difference = DateTime.now - current_user.created_at` line)

```
expected numeric or date
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Time.zone.now` (http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html).